# Fixed footer in android layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, footer

Here is my layout for fixed footer. A `Fragment` containing `RecyclerView` is attached to `FrameLayout`. But the content of `RecyclerView` is being overlapped by the footer layout.

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/home_parent_framelayout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer_linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#f1c21e"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <footer layout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `FrameLayout` give property

```
android:layout_above="@+id/footer_linearlayout"
```

it will display both `FrameLayout` and `Footer`.

Add this way :

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/home_parent_framelayout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer_linearlayout" />
```

**Explanation :**

your `LinearLayout` does not display `Bottom` whenever you are creating fix Footer your parent Child `Layout` you have to give `layout_above` property to to the height of the Fix Footer means in your case `LinearLayout`. Height so to display `LinearLayout` in the screen the parent Child `FrameLayout` you have to give `android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout`..

Comment: framelayout has height as wrap content so when i add  android:layout_above="@+id/footer_linearlayout" the framelayout layout is displayed above footer but leaves a lot of empty space above it(framelayout) as it has height wrap content.

Comment: then give `FrameLayout` height to `match_parent` it will take full height to `FrameLayout`. it will solve your Problem..

Comment: @Androidjack glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_parent_framelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer_linearlayout" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer_linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#f1c21e"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

//Your footer layout
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```